# JavaScript: Insert line breaks and spaces into XML and JSON strings?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I have the following strings:

```xml
<xml><test myAttr="test123">Test</test></xml>
```

```json
{"abc":"123","xyz":[{"num":1,"bool":true}]}
```

I would like to automatically add line breaks and spaces/tabs in order to format these like this:

```xml
<xml>
  <test myAttr="test123">Test</test>
</xml>
```

```json
{
  "abc": "123",
  "xyz": [
    {
      "num":1,
      "bool":true
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm then going to use [highlightjs.org](https://highlightjs.org/) to create a HTML string to display in the browser.

Does anyone know of a JavaScript library or any language features to that can do this easily..?

Comment: You might want to check https://github.com/ericpony/google-code-prettify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can use the Prettier API:

https://prettier.io/docs/en/api.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at npm package [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify). Works for JS, JSON, XML and CSS and you can specify indentation size, max empty lines, brace style etc. There's a Demo here: https://beautifier.io/.